# totem/videos wouldn't resume after pause

Tags: video, gstreamer, resume, totem

I have a problem that Totem/Videos *sometimes* woudln't resume after a pause.
In these cases, however, it would resume play if I make any seek operation.

I tried to patch it playing with 'async' property of the cluttersink used by totem (as suggested in: [How to resume playing after paused using gstreamer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547500/how-to-resume-playing-after-paused-using-gstreamer)) - but it didn't change the behavior.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide gstreamer version? Is any of the samples your are using public?

Comment: I'm using gstreamer 1.0 (1.2.4). One of the samples I'm using Big-Buck-Bunny https://peach.blender.org/download/, specifically the 720x1280, mp4 format.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning, is that when I enable some debug prints (e.g. GST_DEBUG=cluttersink) the issue is resolved. So it appears as something depending on timing.

Comment: Are you playing local files or via http? It seems to work here with gstreamer 1.4

Comment: Local files.
Also, I run on a slow machine.

Answer (score 0):

My original patch to Totem has replaced autoaudiosink with fakesink.
When I returned the sink to autoaudiosink the problem was solved.

It appears that Totem derives its clock from the audio stream, and for some reason using fakesink for audio sink make the pause operation malfunctioning.