# Which state in gstreamer indicates that the pipeline is working correctly?

Tags: linux, gstreamer

Concerning Gstream state changes, we should send a event when the pipeline is working correctly (Stream OK) and when there is an error we should send another event (Stream Error).

Catching errors over the message callback works, but we don't know which state indicate that the full pipeline is working correctly (from src to sync).

Comment: I'don't know the complete answer but this may give a starting point. Whenever I have a problem with the pipeline I receive error indicating it is having problems setting state to `PAUSED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific error state in GStreamer ([GStreamer states](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/basics/states.html) are: NULL, READY, PAUSED, PLAYING (*)). Thus, you need to watch and check if any error occurs. You should check, at least:

- the [return value](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstElement.html#GstStateChangeReturn) of the function for changing the state ([`gst_element_set_state`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstElement.html#GstState))
- if any error message is sent to the bus:

  > Errors can be received by listening to the GstBus of the
  >   element/pipeline for GstMessage objects with the type
  >   GST_MESSAGE_ERROR or GST_MESSAGE_WARNING. The thrown errors should be
  >   inspected, and filtered if appropriate.

(*) Note: actually, the complete [list of states in the API](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstElement.html#GstState) includes also a *pending* state that may be relevant in some cases (see e.g. [How to resume playing after paused using gstreamer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547500/how-to-resume-playing-after-paused-using-gstreamer))